# Javascript object containing multiple keys & checking all values

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
<button className={`actionBoxButton ${props.moves[0].moveName !== "FirstPassMove" && props.moves[0].moveName !== "PassMove"  ? "actionBoxButtonGrey" : ''}`}
```

props.moves looks like this:

```
{userId: 30, moveId: 60, moveName: "FirstSettlementMove", building: {…}}
1: {userId: 30, moveId: 62, moveName: "FirstSettlementMove", building: {…}}
2: {userId: 30, moveId: 64, moveName: "FirstSettlementMove", building: {…}}
3: {userId: 30, moveId: 66, moveName: "FirstSettlementMove", building: {…}}
4: {userId: 30, moveId: 68, moveName: "FirstSettlementMove", building: {…}}
5: {userId: 30, moveId: 70, moveName: "FirstSettlementMove", building: {…}}
6: {userId: 30, moveId: 72, moveName: "FirstSettlementMove", building: {…}}
7: {userId: 30, moveId: 74, moveName: "FirstSettlementMove", building: {…}}
```

This checks if in the props.move (which is an object not an array) element 0 has a key moveName !== FirstPassMove or PassMove. But I do not want to check for element 0 only but all elements of the object. Some said I should use Array.some but since it is not an array that did not work.

Greetings

Comment: Please show how `props.move` looks like beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

What you needs in your case is `Object.values` from that object and iterate over it.

Example:

```js
const moves = {
  0: {
    moveName: "FirstPassMove"
  },
  1: {
    moveName: "PassMove"
  },  
  2: {
    moveName: "Other"
  },
}

const isTheRightMove = Object.values(moves).some(move => ["FirstPassMove", "PassMove"].includes(move.moveName))

console.log(isTheRightMove) // true

const moves2 = {
  0: {
    moveName: "Other"
  },
  1: {
    moveName: "Other"
  },  
  2: {
    moveName: "Other"
  },
}



const isTheRightMove2 = Object.values(moves2).some(move => ["FirstPassMove", "PassMove"].includes(move.moveName))

console.log(isTheRightMove2) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do in this way

```
<button className={`actionBoxButton ${props.moves.find((move) => move.moveName !== "FirstPassMove" && move.moveName !== "PassMove") != null  ? "actionBoxButtonGrey" : ''}`}
```

Comment: this gives me an error that find(move) is not a function